# Oracle Apex Checkboxes doexn't update with Dynamic Actions

Tags: checkbox, oracle-apex

I'm using Apex 19.1 on an 18.c database.
I have a page with three page items and three corresponding Dynamic Actions (DA's). When either **P273_START_DATE** or **P273_END_DATE** are changed, their dynamic actions perform as expected. They refresh a chart region.
I also have a third page item - P273_WEEKDAY_SELECTOR. The DA associated with it is the problem.  The page item has the following characteristics:

```
Identification / Type = checkbox.
List of Values / Type = Static Values
List of Values / Static Values = Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri
Source / Used = Only when current value in session state is null
Source / Maintain Session State = Per Session (Disk)
```

The page item **P273_WEEKDAY_SELECTOR** is contained in the region **From / To Date Selection** along with the two date fields.
The Chart region, **Weekday Attendance** has the following notable characteristic

```
Source / Page Items to Submit = P273_WEEKDAY_SELECTOR
```

The Dynamic Action has the following Characteristics

```
Identification / Name = P273_WEEKDAY_SELECTOR_CHANGE
When / Event = Change
When / Selection Type = Item(s)
When / Items = P273_WEEKDAY_SELECTOR
```

True Action #1

```
Identification / Action = Execute PL/SQL Code
Settings / PL/SQL Code = null;
Settings / Items to Submit = P273_WEEKDAY_SELECTOR
Settings / Items to Return = P273_WEEKDAY_SELECTOR
Settings / Suppress Change Event = No
Execution Options / Event = P273_WEEKDAY_SELECTOR_CHANGE
```

True Action #2

```
Identification / Action = Refresh
Affected Elements / Selection Type = Region
Affected Elements / Region = Weekday Attendance
Execution Options / Event = P273_WEEKDAY_SELECTOR_CHANGE
```

In trying to solve this problem, I created a temporary region **TEST_REGION** with a page item **P273_WEEKDAY_TEST**. I added a temporary True Action #3 to update TEST_REGION. The page item P273_WEEKDAY_TEST has the following characteristics:

```
Source / Type = SQL Query (return colon separated value)
Source / SQL Query = Select '''' || regexp_replace(:P273_weekday_selector, ':', ''', ''' ) || '''' from dual;
```

When I change the selected checkboxes the page item **P273_WEEKDAY_TEST** doesn't get updated with the DA for the checkbox. However, if I press the browser's refresh button, the item **P273_WEEKDAY_TEST** gets updated with the proper values e.g. 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Fri'

This setup doesn't seem to fire on change of the checkbox, yet the other DA's fire when either date is changed. How do I made a DA work for change of a checkbox item?

Comment: don't you have to add P273_weekday_selector to ITEMS TO SUBMIT area?

Comment: Thanks for replying Oguen,  I had already added P273_WEEKDAY_SELECTOR to the chart region's "Source / Page Items to Submit".  It's interesting to note that I didn't have to add the two date page items to the chart's "Source / Page Items to Submit", and they work fine.

Comment: Hello Again Oguen.  Additionally, I had already added P273_WEEKDAY_SELECTOR to the Chart's "Series / Source / Page Items to Submit".

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with the Dynamic Action. The problem was with the SQL for the chart's Series. It was referencing a page item that was a Checkbox.  That stores values in the format: **Mon:Tue:Fri**  If those were the three options checked.
I changed the last line of the SQL's WHERE clause to replace the colons.  Here's the final SQL for the chart's Series:

```
Select
      ls.prim_key
    , ls.weekday
    , to_char(ls.liturgy_date, 'MON-DD-YYYY') as "Event_Date"
    , NVL(ls.count_online, 0) as "Online"
    , 'Online' series
From 
      LITURGY_STATS ls
Where
    ls.prim_key is not null And
    trunc(ls.event_date) >= :P273_start_date And
    trunc(ls.event_date) <= :P273_end_date And
    ls.weekday in (select replace(column_value,'''') from table(apex_string.split(:P273_WEEKDAY_SELECTOR,':')))
Order by    
    ls.event_date;
```

In my original version, the last line of the where clause handled the value of "P273_WEEKDAY_SELECTOR as a whole string (not separated values).  Someone suggested that I use the apex_string.split function, it solved the problem.
Everything works fine now.